# How to get all directories Microsoft Entra user is part of?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

We want to find the directory details in which user is a member. In Portal, these are found in `Directories + Subscriptions` tab.
How to get the same details using Azure API?
We found this API but getting only one organisation
 `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization`
Is there a way for all organization's details in one API call? Thanks, Damodhar

Comment: Could you include more details like how you are generating the access token, with what authentication flow by editing your question?

Comment: curl -X POST "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "client_id=id&client_secret=xxxx&scope=Directory.Read.All&grant_type=password&username=usermail&password=xxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that, you cannot get all the organizations details using Microsoft Graph API. Alternatively, you can use **Azure Management API** to fetch all the organizations associated to your account.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted below **API permission** in it:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using username password flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
username: admin@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below **Azure Management API** call with generated token, I got list of organizations successfully as below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Tenants - List - REST API (Azure Resource Management) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list?view=rest-resources-2022-12-01&tabs=HTTP)

Answer (score 1):

there isn't a single API call that provides details for all organizations in a tenant.Microsoft Graph APi provides the organiztion endpoint, but it returns information about the organization to which the authenticated user belongs, so if you want information about the directories in which a user is a member, you might need to use the /me/memberOf endpoint to get the list of groups, directory roles, and administrative.

```html
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
```

If you need more info on Microsoft graph API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Microsoft%20Graph%20API%20&category=QnA

Comment: Result does not contain what I want:(  No other way possible?

Comment: You can use this Azure management API call: GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01